JanusGraph edges from Java do not appear in Gremlin console
I'm running a JanusGraph server and client per the instructions here. I included an argument to expose port 8182 so I can connect to it from a Java application.
My Java application just creates a new vertex and adds an edge to an existing vertex. When connecting via Java the vertex and edge count look correct. When I look at the vertex count from the Gremlin console the vertex count looks good, but there are no edges.
Even odder is the first edge appears in Gremlin console. After that nothing appears, but the count from Java increments as expected.
Gist of the Java:
import org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.dsl.graph.__;
import static org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal;

g = traversal().withRemote("conf/remote-graph.properties");
System.out.println(g.V().count().next());
System.out.println(g.E().count().next());
g.addV("city")).addE("contains").from(__.V().hasLabel("country")).next();

On the gremlin side I'm checking with commands like:
g.V().count()
g.E().count()
g.V().hasLabel('country').out()

I can not figure out what is going on here.

Did you try a Docker Image to do the same? JG is complex to configure. At least you'd get some data points.
